# In python, I want to get values from a different row meeting some conditions and then create a new column

Tags: python, pandas

In Python, I want to write the code that sets the values of column f to the b value of column of the row if the values ​​of column d and e are the same, and if the values ​​of columns d and e are different, the value of column b of the row that the values of column e of that row and d of the row are the same. For example, I want to create a new column f like the following.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8GmJ.png]

| a | b | c | d | e | f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| nan | 1 | nan | 11 | 13 | 3 |
| nan | 2 | nan | 12 | 13 | 3 |
| nan | 3 | nan | 13 | 13 | 3 |
| nan | 4 | nan | 14 | 16 | 6 |
| nan | 5 | nan | 15 | 16 | 6 |
| nan | 6 | nan | 16 | 16 | 6 |

This is the code I have tried so far.

```
df['f'] = df.apply(df['b'] if df['d'] == df['e'] else df[df['d'] == df['e'],'b'].values
```

Hopefully, someone can help me with this problem. Many thanks !!

Comment: can you add your expected output?

Comment: @Umar.H. I think the expected output is the `f` column.  `df['f'] = df...`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `where` to mask values where `d != e` then use `groupby_transform` to broadcast the values to all row of the group:

```
df['f'] = (df['b'].where(df['d'] == df['e'])
                  .groupby(df['e']).transform('first')
                  .astype(pd.Int64Dtype()))
print(df)

# Output
   b   d   e  f
0  1  11  13  3
1  2  12  13  3
2  3  13  13  3
3  4  14  16  6
4  5  15  16  6
5  6  16  16  6
```

Details about `where`:

```
>>> df['b'].where(df['d'] == df['e'])
0    NaN  # d != e (group 13)
1    NaN  # d != e (group 13)
2    3.0  # d == e (group 13)
3    NaN  # d != e (group 16)
4    NaN  # d != e (group 16)
5    6.0  # d == e (group 16)
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!
However, I don't know why, but when I apply the code you gave me to my data, an error occurs. But except for this part ".astype(df['e'].dtype)", it runs without errors.

Comment: But I ran into another problem. The values ​​in column b of my data are large values, but when I use the code you gave me, the last 4 digits of the values ​​in column f appear as 0000. (for example 1234567890123450000). I appreciate it again if you can help me with this problem.

Comment: What is the output of `print(df['Tweets'].dtype.name)`? `object`?

Comment: In Python, when running the code, the data type is int64.
However, when I saved the values in excel files, I saved those as 'text' type to avoid losing the last 4 digits. (because excel supports only 15 digits)
I import the excel files and using those now.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Tweet dataset!

Comment: If you don't use `astype` and you export to excel, does it display correctly?

Comment: No, the last 4 digits of the values ​​in column f appear as I described, i.e., 1234567890123450000

Comment: Sorry for `astype` is not `e` but `b`!!! I fixed my answer. However it should not solve your other problem. I'm not a specialist of Excel but I think you can use `openpyxl` or `xlsxwriter`. I propose you to ask a new question. I'm really sorry for that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Helped me a lot. I'll try to find a solution by creating a new question!

Comment: @SEan1820. Thanks to your other question, I understand why you can't use `astype`. It's because you have some groups where `d`  is never equal to `e`. Try: `.astype(pd.Int64Dtype())`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code that should achieve the desired result:

```py
df['f'] = df.apply(lambda x: df.loc[(df['d']==x['e']) & (df['e']==x['d']), 'b'].values[0] if (df['d']==df['e']).any() else x['b'], axis=1)
```

Explanation:

The `apply()` method is used to apply a function to each row of the `DataFrame`.

The lambda function takes a row (`x`) as input and checks if the values in columns `d` and `e` are equal (i.e., `if df['d']==df['e']` returns `True` for any row).
If the values are equal, the lambda function looks for the value of `b` in the row where `d` and `e` are reversed (i.e., `d` of the current row matches `e` of another row, and 'e' of the current row matches `d` of that same row).

The `.loc` method is used to locate the row(s) that meet the condition using boolean indexing, and the `.values` attribute is used to extract the value(s) of `b` as a numpy array.

The `[0]` index is used to extract the first (and only) value of `b` from the numpy array.

If the values in columns `d` and `e` are not equal for any row, the lambda function simply returns the value of `b` for the current row.

The `axis=1` argument is used to apply the lambda function row-wise.