# When copying large numbers to a new column, the last 4 digits of numbers greater than 15 digits come out as 0

Tags: python, excel

I'm using tweet data and I have one problem. I'm currently writing code to solve this problem.

========================================================================

[[Previous question]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76213190/in-python-i-want-to-get-values-from-a-different-row-meeting-some-conditions-and)
In Python, I want to write the code that sets the values of column f to the b value of column of the row if the values ​​of column d and e are the same, and if the values ​​of columns d and e are different, the value of column b of the row that the values of column e of that row and d of the row are the same. For example, I want to create a new column f like the following.
[image]

Solution:

```
df['f'] = (df['b'].where(df['d'] == df['e'])
              .groupby(df['e']).transform('first')
.astype(df['b'].dtype))
print(df)
```

However, when applying the code to the following data set, the code doesn't work
[image]

```
data = {
'column_1': [1, 2, 4, 2],
'column_2': [2, 3, 3, 2],
'column_3': ['value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3', 'value_4']
}
dff = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
print(dff)
```

But, when removing '.astype(df['column_2'].dtype))' part, it works.

```
dff['column_4'] = (dff['column_3'].where(dff['column_1'] == dff['column_2'])
              .groupby(dff['column_2']).transform('first'))
print(dff)
```

========================================================================

So, when applying the solution code without 'astype' part to my dataset, it runs, but there is a problem with numbers being cut off.
The values ​​in column b of my data are large values, but when I use the code you gave me, the last 4 digits of the values ​​in column f appear as 0000. (for example, 1234567890123450000).

It probably has something to do with the problem that when I first save the data to an Excel file, digits greater than 15 come out as 0. To solve the problem, I saved the values ​​in text format. (The data type of b,d, and e are int64 in Python. When printing out 'dtype') I would like to solve this problem in Python or Excel.

Hopefully, someone can help me with this problem. Many thanks !!

Comment: It appears you're mixing code from two solutions, some code references `df`, while the other uses `dff` and the column names are mixed up as well. It's unclear what problem you're having exactly - something doesn't work, but what doesn't? Do you get surprising error messages? If so, please share the full stack trace. Does the output look different from what you expected? If so, please share the output you're getting and explain how you expected it to be different. You can't expect us to take code that doesn't run by itself and get the same results you're getting by chance.

Comment: Running your example code with the type change will result in an error because the strings can't be converted to integers. It's unclear from the test data how the problem you describe for very large numbers comes about.

Comment: I made two data sets so those have different names, df and dff.
My issue is that the output look different from what you expected.

Comment: When reading Excel data, the data comes out correctly, but when copying to a new column, the number format changes. For example, 1234567890123456789 is the original data (in both Excel and Python), but when copied the value to a new column, it comes out like 1234567890123450000 (the actual form is 1.234567E+18) and the numbers after 15 digits appear as 0.
I want to solve this problem.
Thank you for your interest!

Answer (score 1):

For your display problem, it's because sometimes you have no rows where `d` column (child) equals `e` column (parent). So, you get some `None` on the `f` column (output). The column is converted as float and Pandas uses the scientific notation. Instead of cast to the dtype of `b` column (source), use `.astype(pd.Int64Dtype())` to allow integer and null values:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({'f': [1234567890123450000, None]})
              f
0  1.234568e+18
1           NaN

>>> pd.DataFrame({'f': [1234567890123450000, None]}).astype(int)
...
IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

>>> pd.DataFrame({'f': [1234567890123450000, None]}).astype(pd.Int64Dtype())
                     f
0  1234567890123450112
1                 <NA>
```

To fix the code, use:

```
df['f'] = (df['b'].where(df['d'] == df['e'])
                  .groupby(df['e']).transform('first')
                  .astype(pd.Int64Dtype()))
```

**Note: for your second case, you can't convert strings as numeric dtype!**

Comment: Thank you so much for your interest and help again! Your code works fine! Thank you so much for helping me solve my problem. I could learn more.
While waiting for your second answer, I applied your previous code after converting the data type of column b from int64 to str, and that also gave me the answer I wanted too!
Thanks to you, I was able to find a solution. 
I appreciate it again, and have a great day!